Apache Iceberg table maintenance
I'm trying to onboard Iceberg table for streaming use-case and I've noticed that maintenance API in Actions is very limited in comparison with SparkActions, just want to understand is it indeed required to use Spark for this purpose or there is a way to do everything with just one engine? Or, it doesn't seems so, but maybe, Flink doesn't require the same maintenance as Spark do?
